# How to fix 'problems connecting to geonames server http://ws.geonames.org'?

Tags: java, geonames

I'm trying to use the geonames API, but I was not able to run the example code given here https://www.geonames.org/source-code/.

```
WebService.setUserName("demo"); // add your username here

  ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
  searchCriteria.setQ("zurich");
  ToponymSearchResult searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
  for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) {
     System.out.println(toponym.getName()+" "+ toponym.getCountryName());
  }
```

I'm always getting the following error message:

```
WARNING: problems connecting to geonames server http://ws.geonames.org
java.net.UnknownHostException: ws.geonames.org
```

So far I have tried to google the error-message but I was not able to find out what I have to change in the code.

Some help in fixing this would be appreciated.

Edit: Fixed it. The following worked for me:

```
WebService.setGeoNamesServer("api.geonames.org"); 
WebService.setUserName("demo"); // add your username here

  ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
  searchCriteria.setQ("zurich");
  ToponymSearchResult searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
  for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) {
     System.out.println(toponym.getName()+" "+ toponym.getCountryName());
  }
```

Thanks @Progman for the help.

Comment: did you try debugging your cools with tools like curl?

Comment: How about posting your code along with the stack trace for the `UnknownHostException` you are getting.

Comment: Well, the host "ws.geonames.org" does indeed not exists, but "api.geonames.org" exists.